# Which machine learning algorithms support a feedback ingestion loop?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

I understand stochastic gradient descent does. any other alorithm which supports incremental training preferably updating on a real time basis?

Answer (score 1):

A few other methods support incremental learning. (Sorry it should be a comment instead but I don't have enough reputation ;)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers on the implimentation of these algorithms?

Comment: since sklearn is open source. I guess you can just check out the source code of the relevant classes.